# C# how to read things like ID3 tag for a video files

Tags: c#, video, mp3, id3

I was wondering if there anyway to read things like ID3 tag for a video file?

Sultan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out TaglibSharp

http://www.novell.com/products/linuxpackages/opensuse11.1/taglib-sharp.html

Answer (score 2):

Try to use taglib-sharp.dll may help.